# click function to show next element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make my menu dynamic.

I have this HTML output:

```
<dl>
    <dt class="odd">one</dt>
    <dd class="odd"> ...</dd>

    <dt class="even">two</dt>
    <dd class="even"> ...</dd>

    <dt class="odd">three</dt>
    <dd class="odd">... </dd>

    <dt class="even">four</dt>
    <dd class="even">... </dd>

    <dt class="odd">five</dt>
    <dd class="odd">... </dd>

    <dt class="even">six</dt>
    <dd class="even">...</dd>
</dl>
```

I've set the `dd` to `display: none` because they are the filters. `dt` are the titles.

I am trying to make it so that I click on a `dt` it must change the next `dd` element to `display: block;`

I was looking for some jQuery or javascript methods to do it, but I cant find any.

Any idea?

Comment: if you search in google to show or hide an element using jquery you got a lot of examples

Comment: I´d know how to make jQuery(.even).show() /hide() ;
The problem is to make dinamic to all and changing in case of the element that you click

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be able to toggle (show/ hide) the `dt`s you can use the [`.toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)-function of jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('dt').on('click', function(){
        $(this).next('dd').toggle();
    });

});
```

The [`$(this)`](http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/08/what-is-this)-object references the clicked element. [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) will select the next element matching the selector, in this case the next `dd`.

To be sure you're binding your event-listener to an existing element, you might have to wrap your code with the [.ready()](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)-listener

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lkd6co0p/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will go to learn how to use it to other sites.
Very usefull !

Answer (score 10):

You can use [next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) which will

> Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements.

```
$('dt').click(function(){
  $(this).next('dd').show();
  });
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ywnhao83/)

Comment: @Mivaweb, just added a demo and going to add description now

Comment: Nice one, its correctly thanks, but it´s more usefull the code of empiric, but thanks !